# I'm using SpringMVC for a web app and i'm using sessionFactory for Hibernate. Following is the pom.xml that i am using

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <groupId>com.amkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
            <name>SpringMVCFirst</name>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <properties>
                <java-version>1.6</java-version>
                <org.springframework-version>3.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
                <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
                <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Spring -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                </dependency>



                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </dependency>


                <!-- need this for @Configuration -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- AspectJ -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Logging -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.15</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!-- @Inject -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                    <version>1</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Servlet -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- Test -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.7</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalProjectnatures>
                                <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                            </additionalProjectnatures>
                            <additionalBuildcommands>
                                <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                            </additionalBuildcommands>
                            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </project>
```

### > And the error is that i see on the console:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4458)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/MappingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1838)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:978)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:783)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:713)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.MappingException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    ... 51 more
Feb 13, 2014 7:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

### > Is it the issue of a jar file mismatch or something is missing?

Can anyone help me out with this?

I also tried using spring.jar....but it did not helped

Answer (score 1):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
             <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
             <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the issue of a jar file mismatch or something is missing?

You are missing a JAR file that defines the class `org.hibernate.MappingException`.

It is safe to say that this is a Hibernate JAR file, and that adding `spring.jar` (whatever that is) wouldn't help.

If you visit the `findjar.com` site and enter the full classname, it will give you a list of JAR files that define that class.

However, I think you would be better off going back to the tutorial (or whatever) that you are using to learn Hibernate, and use the JARs that they recommend.  Or read the Hibernate 3.3 Tutorial starting at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html.  I notice that your POM file doesn't include any Hibernate dependencies.